# Poco C++ статическая сборка

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, poco

Нужно сделать статическую сборку библиотеки Poco для С++, в общем я склонировал репозиторий Poco с официального git, и ввёл следующие команды:

```
./configure --static --no-tests --no-samples
make
```

Создалась папка "lib", где лежат .a файлы для подключения в свой проект. Путь таков: `lib/Linux/x86_64/libPocoX.a` где x - название нужного мне модуля. Например мне нужен модуль Foundation, то это будет `lib/Linux/x86_64/libPocoFoundation.a`.

Далее я пытался подключить эти файлы в свой проект, написал данный CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(ots_grunt)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
add_definitions( -DPOCO_STATIC )
option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)

# Исходные файлы
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES "main.cpp" "src/*.cpp" "src/*.h")

add_executable(ots_grunt ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    /home/atfaive/poco/lib/Linux/x86_64/libPocoUtil.a
    /home/atfaive/poco/lib/Linux/x86_64/libPocoNetSSL.a
    /home/atfaive/poco/lib/Linux/x86_64/libPocoJSON.a
    /home/atfaive/poco/lib/Linux/x86_64/libPocoNet.a
    /home/atfaive/poco/lib/Linux/x86_64/libPocoFoundation.a
    /home/atfaive/poco/lib/Linux/x86_64/libPocoXML.a
    /home/atfaive/poco/lib/Linux/x86_64/libPocoData.a
    /home/atfaive/poco/lib/Linux/x86_64/libPocoPrometheus.a
)
```

Но при сборке у меня пошли ошибки такого рода:

1. Session.cpp:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `SSL_SESSION_free' /usr/bin/ld: /home/atfaive/poco/lib/Linux/x86_64/libPocoNetSSL.a(Session.o): in function` Poco::Net::Session::~Session()':
2. /usr/bin/ld: Thread.cpp:(.text+0xe35): undefined reference to `pthread_sigmask'

Comment: Открой сам `configure.sh` и погляди какие там есть флаги

Comment: `./configure --help`

Comment: А вообще он CMake ом билдится. Нафига тогда make?

Comment: Все верно. Однако линкуя статически библиотеку POCO вы должны еще линковать все ее зависимости.

Comment: @megorit так если билдить cmake'ом, то оно делает .so файлы

Comment: @user7860670 т.е собирать openssl, pthread, и после чего их линковать при сборке в poco?

Comment: Нет, линковать их к своему исполняемому файла. pthread имеет смысл использовать системный

Comment: @user7860670 т.е в target_link_libraries указать ssl?

Comment: так же я так понял что нужно указывать .a файлы в каком то строгом порядке?

Comment: Да, и библиотеки должны указываться после тех единиц трансляции, которые требуют их символы

Comment: @user7860670 а как возможно определить этот порядок? Не подскажите?

Comment: Необходимо знать, какие символы откуда берутся.

Comment: @user7860670 я увидел в документации Poco это: 
To link statically, the code using the POCO C++ Libraries must be compiled with the preprocessor symbol POCO_STATIC defined. Я так понял нужно указать препроцессор POCO_STATIC в CMakeLists?

Comment: Обычно так `cmake -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF`

Comment: @megorit попробовал собрать с этим флагом, всё равно идут ошибки: /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/ots_grunt.dir/src/OtsLogger.cpp.o: in function `OtsLogger::initializeLogger()':
OtsLogger.cpp:(.text+0x155): undefined reference to `Poco::FormattingChannel::FormattingChannel(Poco::Formatter*, Poco::Channel*)'
/usr/bin/ld: OtsLogger.cpp:(.text+0x1b1): undefined reference to `Poco::Logger::setChannel(Poco::Channel*)'

Comment: Вероятно модуль какой-то не подключен.

Comment: Используйте `find_package`. Подключите необходимые модули. Читайте документацию. Там должно быть указано где какие модули, зависимости и т.д.